# Laravel Exception explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:165

Tags: laravel, queue, rabbitmq

I am looking for help, I am using queues with RabbitMQ, I have installed `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` and all ok, but recently I started to get some errors, It's really odd because it just happen sometimes.

It throws

> local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/frontend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:165,

I check the function parseJob from `Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job` , and dump the parameter `$job`, sometimes it receives a string like `Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call`, but others receives an instance like

```
{
    "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"App\\Jobs\\SendPost",
    "log":[],
    "post": {
        "class":"App\\Models\\Post",
        "id":72
    },
    "start":1491338912.0843,
    "connection":null,
    "queue":"front_send_post_0",
    "delay":null
}
```

this are my classes:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

class CheckSendPost implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    const TOTAL_QUEUES = 3;

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $posts = Post::getRedyToPost(date('Y-m-d H:i'), null, 0);
            $count = 0;

            Log::info('front_check_send_post: ' . count($posts));

            if (count($posts)) {
                foreach($posts as $post) {   
                        dispatch(
                            (new \App\Jobs\SendPost($post))
                            ->onQueue('front_send_post_' . ($count%self::TOTAL_QUEUES))
                        );

                    $count++;
                }
            }

            dispatch(
                (new \App\Jobs\CheckSendPost)
                ->onQueue('front_check_send_post')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::info('ERROR ' . $e->getCode() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}


namespace App\Jobs;

class SendPost implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $post = null;
    public $start = null;

    public function __construct(Post $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->start = microtime(true);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Post: '.$this->post->id);

        try {
            $this->post->publish();
            $this->post->setSuccess();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->post->setError();
        } finally {
            $this->post->save();
        }

        Log::info(
            date('d-m-Y H:i:s').', '.
            round((microtime(true) - $this->start), 4).' seg, '.
            'Mem '.Helper::formatBytes(memory_get_usage()).', '.
            'Max Mem '.Helper::formatBytes(memory_get_peak_usage())
        );
    }
}
```

and using

- PHP Version 5.6.29
- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Laravel 5.3

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your namespaces are all correct.

`__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` indicates that the class was not found when it was being unserialized. See question: [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272813/php-incomplete-class-name-wrong)